# Impedance for TTL Hsync and Vsync Pulses

Tags: pcb, analog, integrated-circuit, impedance-matching, termination

I'm just finishing up a sync combiner and audio/video PCB. I'm trying to impedance match my traces and I've done so for the 75 ohm RGB lines. Now I'm looking at the TTL level Hsync and Vsync lines that go into a 74LS86, and from there are outputted to a 470 ohm resistor to bring the Csync down to 75 ohm levels.

My question is, can I use 75 ohm impedance traces for the TTL level sync lines or is there a more ideal value I should aim for? I've read 50 ohm, 60 ohm and 75 ohm from various sources so I'm confused. If the value is different, once the combined sync comes out would I switch the traces back to 75 ohm impedance due to the 470 ohm resistor bringing it down to 75 ohm?

Oh, and to make sure I'm getting the right information, I'm using this coplanar waveguide calculator (http://spok.ca/index.php/resources/tools/99-cpwcalc) and I'm a little confused with it. It asks for substrate height and the dielectric gap between the trace and the ground plane beside it. The height is the thickness of the board, such as 1.6mm I think. Is the gap only one side of the dielectric or both sides beside the trace combined?

[Anyways, here's my circuit even though it isn't really needed to answer the question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2HlH.jpg)

Comment: The output impedance of your driver is much higher than 75 Ohms so it is already grossly mismatched, and the trace is short so its impedance won't have a significant effect.

Comment: When you say "driver", are you referring to the 74LS86 or the 470 ohm resistor? That resistor value is used in most older game consoles for 75 ohm level sync, aside from the Super Nintendo which uses 330 ohms.

Comment: "When you say "driver", are you referring to the 74LS86 or the 470 ohm resistor?" - Both. Total output impedance is the combination of driver's internal impedance plus the resistor. The impedance mismatch will put a step in the waveform, but at standard VGA sync frequency it shouldn't be a problem unless you use a very long cable.

Comment: Got it. I'm going to make the traces 75 ohm impedance anyways as I need to minimize reflections in the videos lines. I need the 470 ohm resistor in place or else I'll blow up consumer equipment, which can't take TTL level sync. Thank you for your input.